# Python - send lines to multiple devices (listed in a text file with IPs)

Tags: python, cisco

I have a script written to push config to network devices and/or print the output from various commands into files, backup etc.

This works perfectly well for individual devices when I define the IP of the device. I am not sure how I can write a loop in order for it to go through a file containing multiple IPs, and for it to run the commands on them one-by-one? Ie. i have a file IP.txt containing this:

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

This is my script:

```
import pexpect

HOST = "1.1.1.1"
user = "user"
password = "pass"

policymap = pexpect.spawn ('telnet '+HOST)
policymap.expect ('Username: ')
policymap.sendline (user)
policymap.expect ('Password: ')
policymap.sendline (password)
routerHostname = "router"
policymap.expect (router+'#')
policymap.sendline ('sh ip int br\r')
```

etc etc.

Just trying to figure out how can I have the script run through a list of IPs in a file and run the commands? Sorry for being amateurish here, I am new to this and working my way through a book to learn properly... but find this very helpful for questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open("IP.txt") as ips:
    all_ips = [x.rstrip() for x in ips] # get all ips in a list and strip newline 
    for ip in all_ips:
        policymap = pexpect.spawn ('telnet '+ ip) # first loop it will be 1.1.1.1, second loop  it will be 2.2.2.2 etc..
```

`all_ips` will look like `['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3']`

Comment: Should the loop be 'for ip in all_ips'

Comment: thanks paddy! i have the file stripped already with IPs line-by-line... not sure how i can pass the IPs to spawn the telnet session ?

Comment: I added to my answer, if your code works for a hardcoded ip then it will work setting the ip each time through the loop